# values not getting posted in php from html for sending mail

Tags: php, html

I have a html form where I need to send mail from PHP. 
I am able to send the mail but its not taking the values from html.

**HTML form:**

```html
<form id="main-contact-form" name="application-form" method="post" action="Applyonline.php">

  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Candidate Name" required="required">
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" name="qualification" class="form-control" placeholder="Qualification" required="required">
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" name="phno" class="form-control" placeholder="Phone Number" required="required" maxlength="10">
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="working">Are You Presently Working</label>
    <input type="radio" name="working" value="yes" checked> Yes
    <input type="radio" name="working" value="no"> No
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
              <button type="submit" class="btn-submit">Apply Now</button>
            </div>
    </form>
```

**PHP code:**

```
 <?php $name       = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['name']));
 $qualification = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['qualification'])); $phno =
 @trim(stripslashes($_POST['phno']));
 $working=@trim(stripslashes($_POST['working']));

 $subject    = "Application";

 $to        = 'wc@example.com';//replace with your email



 $message    =  " <html> <head>

 </head> <body> <p>This email contains HTML Tags!</p> <table> <tr>
 <td>Candidate Name:</th> <td>$name</td> </tr>

 <tr> <td>Qualification:</th> <td>$qualification</td> </tr> <tr>
 <td>Phone Number:</th> <td>$phno</td> </tr> <tr> <td>Are you
 Presently Woring:</th> <td>$working</td> </tr>

 </table> </body> </html> ";

 // Always set content-type when sending HTML email $headers =
 "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n"; $headers .=
 "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n"; // More headers
 $headers .= 'From: <$from>' . "\r\n";

 mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);

 ?>
```

Its not taking the values for $name,$qualification etc...I am not getting what's the issue in the above form.

Kindly help, thanks in advance.

Comment: Please add proper code and more information. form end is there but where is the form start tag?

Comment: Your php code is unreadable. Format it properly pls.

Comment: Don't put `<>` around your variables: `<$qualification>` will be interpreted as HTML tag and thus not show up

Answer (score 0):

In your `$message` you put `<>` around your variables, which will then be interpreted as HTML tags and thus not show in your mail. Replace your `$message` with

```
$message    =  " <html> <head>
</head> <body> <p>This email contains HTML Tags!</p> <table> <tr>
<td>Candidate Name:</td> <td>$name</td> </tr>
<tr> <td>Qualification:</td> <td>$qualification</td> </tr> <tr>
<td>Phone Number:</td> <td>$phno</td> </tr> <tr> <td>Are you
Presently Working:</td> <td>$working</td> </tr>
</table> </body> </html> ";
```

and they should show up in your mail.

Comment: Edited the code again, changed your faulty `</th>`s to `</td>`s

Comment: On a side note: if that's how your code is formatted you should probably also change `// Always set content-type when sending HTML email $headers =` ... because `$headers` will never be set